# Shifting touch focus from one recycle view to another

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development and got stuck with this.

I have implemented drag and drop for recycle view using ItemTouchHelper.Callback. Now drag and drop is working perfectly within the recycler view. But in my case, i have two recycler views and i want to drag item from one recycler view to another. Is there any ways to achieve this using ItemTouchHelper.Callback?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: maybe a little late, but I've implemented exactly what you need using 2 recycler views.   All I did was use the swipe-to-delete pattern to remove from one recycler to the other.  https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.em4m4cs9m